# Ifxpy library problem in order to connect to informix database in linux

Tags: python-3.x, informix

I want to connect to the Informix database using ifxpy library in Python in order to call some stored procedures in my code.
according to [ifxpy github](https://github.com/OpenInformix/IfxPy), I installed ifxpy. I already installed all preconditions package like wheel and twine and JRE and client-SDK.

also, I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH and it seems everything is ok, but when I import ifxpy library, I see this error message,=.

```
ImportError: /home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IfxPy.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: SQLGetFunctions
```

I'm not familiar a lot with Informix, anybody can help me?

my os is Ubuntu 20.0.4 and my python version is python 3.8.10.
also, I test it with python3.10 but it didn't work too.

Comment: Do you have UnixODBC installed on that box?  Also, make sure you have INFORMIXDIR environment variable set to the install directory, and LD_LIBRARY_PATH to $INFORMIXDIR/lib:$INFORMIXDIR/lib/esql:$INFORMIXDIR/cli.

Comment: @jsagrera
yes, in my os, INFORMIXDIR is set to /opt/IBM/Informix_Client-SDK
and LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set to /opt/IBM/Informix_Client-SDK/lib:/opt/IBM/Informix_Client-SDK/lib/esql:/opt/IBM/Informix_Client-SDK/lib/cli

Also i installed UnixODBC, but the problem not solved yet.

Comment: Try adding those globally. Instead of LD_LIBRARY_PATH use a file in the `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` directory. If it works at least you will know is due Python not using LD_LIBRARY_PATH which I think it was an due a security change  around 3.7x.
It will be a good idea to validate that ODBC works (as that is what IfxPy uses) with UnixODBC `isql` tool.  
Another thing to try is using the "lite" CSDK runtime from `https://hcl-onedb.github.io/odbc/OneDB-Linux64-ODBC-Driver.tar`. Extract it somewhere and point LD_LIBRARY_PATH or `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/xxx` file to those dirs.

Comment: Check https://github.com/OpenInformix/IfxPy/issues/22 for the `ld.so.conf.d` suggestion ;)